# Search view is not working on map API

Tags: android, google-maps, autocomplete, searchview

I'm using this [code](http://wptrafficanalyzer.in/blog/adding-google-places-autocomplete-api-as-custom-suggestions-in-android-search-dialog), and I'm getting false value in

```
if(intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_SEARCH))
```

this condition, so Search view is not working. Appreciate any help.

MapsActivity

```
public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<Cursor>,OnMapReadyCallback {
    private GoogleMap mMap;
    private PopupMenu supportMenuInflater;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);

        SupportMapFragment fragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mMap = fragment.getMap();
        Log.e("MAP"," load");
        handleIntent(getIntent());
    }

    private void handleIntent(Intent intent){
        Log.e("handle intent"," load"+intent);

        Log.e("handle intent"," rate "+intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_SEARCH));

        if(intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_SEARCH))
        {
            Log.e("handle intent"," if"+intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_SEARCH));
            doSearch(intent.getStringExtra(SearchManager.QUERY));
        }
        else if(intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_VIEW))
        {
            Log.e("handle intent"," else if");
            getPlace(intent.getStringExtra(SearchManager.EXTRA_DATA_KEY));
        }
        else
        {
            Log.e("handle intent"," else");
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
        super.onNewIntent(intent);
        setIntent(intent);
        handleIntent(intent);
    }

    private void doSearch(String query){
        Log.e("Dosearch"," load "+query);
        Bundle data = new Bundle();
        data.putString("query", query);
        getSupportLoaderManager().restartLoader(0, data, this);
    }

    private void getPlace(String query){
        Log.e("getPlace"," load "+query);
        Bundle data = new Bundle();
        data.putString("query", query);
        getSupportLoaderManager().restartLoader(1, data, this);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
            SearchManager manager = (SearchManager) getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
            SearchView search = (SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id.action_search).getActionView();
            search.setIconifiedByDefault(false);
            search.setSearchableInfo(manager.getSearchableInfo(getComponentName()));
            search.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onQueryTextChange(String query) {
                    doSearch(query);
                    return true;
                }

                @Override
                public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
                    return false;
                }
            });
        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onMenuItemSelected(int featureId, MenuItem item) {
        switch(item.getItemId()){
            case R.id.action_search:
                onSearchRequested();
                break;
        }
        return super.onMenuItemSelected(featureId, item);
    }
    @Override
    public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int arg0, Bundle query) {
        CursorLoader cLoader = null;
        if(arg0==0)
            cLoader = new CursorLoader(getBaseContext(), PlaceProvider.SEARCH_URI, null, null, new String[]{ query.getString("query") }, null);
        else if(arg0==1)
            cLoader = new CursorLoader(getBaseContext(), PlaceProvider.DETAILS_URI, null, null, new String[]{ query.getString("query") }, null);
        return cLoader;
    }

    @Override
    public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> arg0, Cursor c) {
        showLocations(c);
    }

    @Override
    public void onLoaderReset(Loader<Cursor> arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

    private void showLocations(Cursor c){
        MarkerOptions markerOptions = null;
        LatLng position = null;
        mMap.clear();
        while(c.moveToNext()){
            markerOptions = new MarkerOptions();
            position = new LatLng(Double.parseDouble(c.getString(1)),Double.parseDouble(c.getString(2)));
            markerOptions.position(position);
            markerOptions.title(c.getString(0));
            mMap.addMarker(markerOptions);
        }
        if(position!=null){
            CameraUpdate cameraPosition = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(position);
            mMap.animateCamera(cameraPosition);
        }
    }
    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap;

        // Add a marker in Sydney and move the camera
        LatLng sydney = new LatLng(-34, 151);
        Log.e("OnReady", String.valueOf(sydney));
        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(sydney).title("Marker in Sydney"));
        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(sydney));
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Error Was in Manifest file 

    enter code here
 <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

    <!-- Protect the map component of the application using application signature -->
    <permission
        android:name="com.example.user.demo.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />

    <!-- Allows to receive map -->
    <uses-permission android:name="com.example.user.demo.MAPS_RECEIVE" />

    <!-- Used by the Google Maps Android API V2 to download map tiles from Google Maps servers -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <!-- Allows the Google Maps Android API V2 to cache map tile data in the device's external storage area -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

    <!-- Allows the Google Maps Android API V2 to use WiFi or mobile cell data (or both) to determine the device's location -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />

    <!-- Allows the Google Maps Android API V2 to use the Global Positioning System (GPS)
    to determine the device's location to within a very small area -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

    <!-- Allows to contact Google Serves -->
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />

    <!-- Google Maps Android API V2 requires OpenGL ES version 2 -->
    <uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MapsActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:launchMode="singleTop" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEARCH" />
            </intent-filter>

            <!-- Points to searchable activity -->
            <meta-data android:name="android.app.default_searchable"
                android:value=".MainActivity" />

            <!-- Points to searchable meta data -->
            <meta-data android:name="android.app.searchable"
                android:resource="@xml/searchable"/>

        </activity>

        <provider
            android:name=".PlaceProvider"
            android:authorities="com.example.user.demo.PlaceProvider"
            android:exported="false" />

        <!-- Specifies the Android API Key, which is obtained from Google API Console -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
            android:value="--------------------------------" />

    </application>
```